# Expected value of area of rectangle within a unit square given arbitrary point $E$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, expected-value

> Question: Suppose we have a unit square ABCD. Arbitrarily, pick a point within the interior of the unit square and call that point E. Let the line through E parallel to AB intersect AD at F and let the line through E parallel to BC intersect DC at G. What is the expected value of the area of the rectangle EFDG?

To start, I plotted everything on the coordinate plane such that $D = (0,0), C = (1,0), B = (1,1), A = (0,1),$ and $E = (x,y)~\text{where}~ 0 < x,y < 1.$ We can observe how the area is just $xy$ and the probability of this occurring would be $\frac{xy}{1} = xy$. Therefore we have to solve for $$E = \sum_{0 < x,y < 1} x^2y^2.$$ This is where I am stuck. How are we supposed to evaluate this summation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you calculate $ E[x^2]$ for the unit square? Then show that $ E = E[x^2] E[y^2]$.  (Note that your E isn't quite valid, because you have to weight it by the probability. As it's currently written, $ E = \infty$.)

Comment: Since this is a continuous probability distribution, the expression for the expectation should be an integral rather than a sum.

Comment: @CalvinLin is it possible for you to write down a solution using that method? thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The point $E (x,y)$ is randomly selected with uniform probability within  the unit square with $A(0,0), B(1,0), C(1,1), D(0,1)$.

Expectation $ \,E(X(1-Y)) \, = x(1-y)$ (area of rectangle $\, DGEF$).

By the way please note, $ \,E(X(1-Y))$ and $E(XY)$ are same given a square.

Joint PDF $f(x,y) = f(x) \,f(y) = 1 \, (0 \leq xy \leq 1) \,$ as,

$f(x) = 1, (0 \leq x \leq 1)$ and same for $f(y)$.

$\displaystyle E(X-XY) = \int_{y = 0}^{1} \int_{x = 0}^{1} f(x,y) \, (x-xy) \, dx \,dy$

Answer (score 0):

You want a double integral not a sum, as Greg Martin commented

and the area is $xy$ not $x^2y^2$

so you want $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 x\,y\, f(x,y)\,dx \,dy$$ where $f(x,y)=1$ since you have a uniform distribution in a unit square